# Should I use SQLite or an Array to store 4k objects?

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am debating whether or not to use SQLite for my app. I have to run through about 4k objects hundreds if not thousands of times per app session.

My question is, does anyone know if using a NSMutableArray will burn through the battery faster (because of processing) than it would if I were using SQLLite? Im almost sure it would save the battery just a tad bit at least.. but do you think the battery savings would be worth refactoring my code?

Comment: Now I'm curious what you are doing that you *have* to run through 4k objects hundreds if not thousands of times

Comment: In a nutshell, scanning (barcodes) and validating tickets. Thats all I can really say about it.

Comment: sounds like you need some smarter data structures... ala spell check tree-ism.  maybe sqlite would be better if the data can be normalized

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to these questions is always the same - It depends entirely on what your objects are and what you are doing with them.

If your code runs fine then don't mess with it. Premature optimization is the road to hell.

Also, if you are concerned about it, Apple provides great tools to measure these kinds of things. Use them - they will tell you far more about for particular case than anyone here can.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The objects contain 5 strings. Im looking at 1 of the strings and if its marked "Y" then I add it to another array and delete it from the main array.

Comment: Yup!! Sounds good to me too! Thanks for making me feel a little better. I am just pretty worried about battery life as the app itself is pretty demanding. (Camera will be open 90% of the time its being used). But theres no avoiding that so it is what it is! and thats how I'm leaving it! :)